# Attach\Upload Files to a list item in Sandboxed Solution

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to attach files to a list item through a sandboxed visual web part programatically. Tried the following options

1. SharePoint Attachments control: Not available for sandboxed solution
2. File Upload Control to attach a file. File Upload control does not work in sandboxed web part
3. Attaching files through ECMASCRIPT for a list item. ECMASCRIPT cannot attach files. It only reads\add\delete\update site data. File operations are not available in ECMASCRIPT

Please help me? I am in need of this immediately...

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I previously bookmarked for uploading via the Client OM, this code should be Sandbox compatible.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2010/03/12/uploading-files-using-client-object-model-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: I found the first method did not work for me until I added a

context.Load(docs);

between lines 10 and 11.